# Would a potentially explosive star live longer if it orbited very close to a black hole due to gravitational and relativistic time dilation?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, time-dilation, observers, estimation

Would a potentially explosive star live longer if it orbited very close to a black hole due to gravitational and relativistic time dilation? Should, according to the time dilation effects, nuclear reactions run slower?

Comment: "live longer"...as seen *by which observer*? Why do you think nuclear reactions might behave differently from any other process?

Comment: A star that was close enough to a black hole that an outside observer saw significant time dilation would experience large tidal forces unless the black hole was huge. The star would likely be pulled apart into an accretion disk and sucked into the black hole

Comment: A simpler example "Relatisvistic time dilation and the muon experiment"  https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02531926/document  the experiment in 1963 https://web.mit.edu/8.13/8.13c/references-fall/muons/frisch-smith-1963.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to an outside observer everything in the star would take longer.   The same thing if we launched a nuclear bomb towards the black hole.  If it got very near the black hole it would nearly stop all processes.  Time is time, and everything that takes time will take longer.  But this is only to an outside observer, like us here on earth.  To someone riding with the bomb, it will take exactly the same amount of time.

(For some reason I can't stop thinking of Slim Pickens right now.)